# Selenium: Getting a Blank White Image when taking Screenshot in Linux Server(using Xvfb)

Tags: linux, selenium, xvfb

Chrome version: 61 to 63

Chrome webdriver: 2.33 to 2.35

I'm unable to get screenshot in my selenium program, which I run using Xvfb.

```
((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

Program runs well on a windows machine, and I get a screenshot using above code. But, when I run the program on a Linux server, using Xvfb I get a blank white screenshot, with nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

That solved my problem:

```
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();  

        HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<>();
        chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);  
        chromePrefs.put("intl.accept_languages", "English");
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);

        chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("enable-automation");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless"); //should be enabled for Jenkins
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); //should be enabled for Jenkins
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920x1080"); //should be enabled for Jenkins
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extenstions");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("force-device-scale-factor=0.65");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("high-dpi-support=0.65");
        chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I lost a day on this same problem and your answer fixed my issues with blank screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

After drilling the web I found a solution and I am more than happy to share it so others don't spend so much time on it.

I added an argument:

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
```

I hope that will work for you